# Python requests POST call with OAuth2 token returns 401

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, python-requests, oauth

I have the following Python function which takes an `access_token` from my company's access token provider and hits the URL stored in `matter_hydration_url`:

```
def hydration_request(access_token, matter_hydration_url):
    hydration_call_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
    response = requests.post(matter_hydration_url, headers=hydration_call_headers)
    response.raise_for_status()
```

I have tested BOTH `access_token` AND `matter_hydration_url` externally, through POSTMAN, and they both work. Unfortunately, in this code, the `response` variable has `status_code` field 401. I think I am mis-using `requests.post()`. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to use FIddler to sniff the call and compare with Postman call. Check (if possible) the logs on _hydration_url_ server

Comment: Include legit headers not only `{'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}` use Fiddler as Max said

Answer (score 0):

Worked after I changed `Bearer` in the String of line 2 to `Access`
¯_(ツ)_/¯